# Symfony2 Service Container - Passing ordinary arguments to service constructor

Tags: php, symfony, constructor, dependency-injection, pagination

I have this `Paginator` class constructor:

```
class Paginator
{    
    public function __construct($total_count, $per_page, $current_page)
    {
    }
}
```

The `Paginator` Service is registered in `Ibw/JobeetBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` like this :

```
parameters:
    ibw_jobeet_paginator.class: Ibw\JobeetBundle\Utils\Paginator

services:
    ibw_jobeet_paginator:
        class: %ibw_jobeet_paginator.class%
```

When i use the `Paginator` like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$total_jobs = $em->getRepository('IbwJobeetBundle:Job')->getJobsCount($id);
$per_page = $this->container->getParameter('max_jobs_on_category');
$current_page = $page; 

$paginator = $this->get('ibw_jobeet_paginator')->call($total_jobs, $per_page, $current_page);
```

I get this exception:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   Ibw\JobeetBundle\Utils\Paginator::__construct(), called in
>   /var/www/jobeet/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line
>   1306 and defined in
>   /var/www/jobeet/src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Utils/Paginator.php line 13

I guess there's something wrong in passing arguments to the `Paginator` service constructor. Could you tell me, How to pass arguments to a service constructor ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, to answer your question, you pass service constructor arguments using the arguments parameter:

```
services:
    ibw_jobeet_paginator:
        class: %ibw_jobeet_paginator.class%
    arguments:
        - 1 # total
        - 2 # per page
        - 3 # current page
```

Of course that does not really help you out much since the parameters are dynamic.

Instead, move the arguments from the constructor to another method:

```
class Paginator
{    
    public function __construct() {}

    public function init($total_count, $per_page, $current_page)
    {
    }
}

$paginator = $this->get('ibw_jobeet_paginator')->init($total_jobs, $per_page, $current_page);
```

Comment: Yea, I did that just to get it working, But having the ability to pass the arguments inside `$this->get()` method would be great.